# Where to find information on homeschooling requirements by state?

Tags: primary-schooler, homeschooling

Is there a place to find homeschooling requirements on a state-by-state basis in the United States (or a listing for other countries as well)?  I am most interested in the requirement for entering a certain grade or skipping between grades, as homeschooled students often can complete curricula ahead of time, but may still not meet state requirements for being in the next grade up.

Comment: Wouldn't this vary so much by state as to be too localized if actually helpful and not a real question if not too localized?

Comment: I think you are right.  These laws are determined by states.  I'll look if there is a resource for the two states in which we spend most of our time.  If any one knows of a good listing by state though, I can't imagine I'm the only one that wants to know.  I'll include it if I find one.

Comment: @balancedmama I approved Justkt's suggested edit, as your question was way too broad as it stood.  Feel free to roll back the changes and make further edits, if you like, but please try to keep any edits as focused and specific as Justkt's version.

Comment: FYI, there is a request at Area 51 to start a Home Schooling site. Worth taking a look if you are interested in Home Schooling. Check it out here ->http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30914/homeschooling?referrer=TkMGXjXNBtQIvgwyv3SPGA2

Comment: Here's a list. It seems our country is surprisingly (or is it unsurprising?) lax on regulations for home schooling http://education.uslegal.com/homeschooling/homeschooling-laws-by-state/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HSLDA is a great resource for this.  https://www.hslda.org/laws/

Comment: +1:  This looks like a great resource.  A friend and I have been having discussions about her homeschooling her daughter, I'm going to share this link with her.  Thanks!